# React Native List View Sticky Headers index 0 was outside of the range

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get the following error using List view for sticky headers:

`Sticky header index 0 was outside of the range {0,0}`

**Code**

```
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  getRowData: (dataBlob, sectionID, rowID) => { return dataBlob[sectionID + '-' + rowID] },
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
  getSectionData: (dataBlob, sectionID) => { return dataBlob[sectionID] },
  sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
});

const list = map.toList().sortBy(item => [item.manufacturer.name,item.mass]);
const {dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs} = this._genDataBlob(list);
const dataSource = ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs);

return (
  <ListView
    style={styles.list}
    dataSource={dataSource}
    renderRow={this._renderRow}
    renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
  />
);
```

**dataBlob**

```
{ 
  1: { HEADER 1 }, 
  1-1: { ROW 1 }, 
  1-2: { ROW 2 },  
  2: { HEADER 2 }, 
  2-1: { ROW 3 }, 
  2-2: { ROW 4 } 
}
```

**sectionIDs**

```
["12", "3", "21", "22", "68", "5", "69", "19", "4", "6", "1", "13", "20"]
```

**rowIDs**

```
[ 
  [ { ROW 1 }, { ROW 2 } ] , 
  [ { ROW 3 }, { ROW 3 } ] 
]
```

I have tried just only passing in DataBlob but has same effect, I have also tried just using the method `cloneWithRows`.

Answer (score 0):

The rowIDs object just needs to just be id's of the rows: `[ 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3' ]`

Answer (score 0):

I thought you may use `if` statement, or things like this, in _renderSectionHeader() function. If so, filling the whole `if` statement with `else` may help you fix this problem.